# Git-Tfs stopped checking in, I can Pull, but Checkin and CheckinTool won't do anything

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I've been using Git-Tfs (https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) for a few months now and love the ability to escape TFS for my personal branches. Until today.

I can pull all I want but when I try to check in (`git tfs checkintool` or `git tfs checkin`) it lists out the files that are about to be checked in and then just dumps me back to the prompt without doing anything.

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

For each command you use, you could use the option -d to see the debug trace and perhaps spot the problem.
Fell free to report your problem with the debug trace (or see if it's already reported), here : https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues

But the better thing to do is to get the source code, compile your version and debug the command which fail. Some help : https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be different letter casing of a folder name. I re-did my operation with the same folder letter casing and it worked

https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/133#issuecomment-12895684